# Strange behaviour of struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I was solving problem 10263 (Railway) of uva online judge (http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=1204) and getting Wrong Answer for my code.
After discussing it with a friend (who also solved the problem and got Accepted) he took a look at my code and it was extremely similar to his (all the geometry functions were the same, for example, since we are training as a team for ICPC and using the same code libraries).

So, after I started trying one change at a time to see what the problem was, I found this strange behaviour.

My initial code (which got Wrong Answer) is this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>
#define EPS 1e-9
using namespace std;

struct point {
    double x, y;
    point(double _x, double _y) { x = _x, y = _y; } //EDITED
    point() { x = 0.0, y = 0.0; }
};

double dist(point p1, point p2) {
    return hypot(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y); 
}

double distToLine(point p, point A, point B, point *c) {
    double scale = (double) ((p.x - A.x) * (B.x - A.x) + (p.y - A.y) * (B.y - A.y)) / ((B.x - A.x) * (B.x - A.x) + (B.y - A.y) * (B.y - A.y));
    c->x = A.x + scale * (B.x - A.x);
    c->y = A.y + scale * (B.y - A.y);
    return dist(p, *c); 
}

double distToLineSegment(point p, point A, point B, point* c) {
    if ((B.x-A.x) * (p.x-A.x) + (B.y-A.y) * (p.y-A.y) < EPS) {
        c->x = A.x; c->y = A.y;
        return dist(p, A); 
    }
    if ((A.x-B.x) * (p.x-B.x) + (A.y-B.y) * (p.y-B.y) < EPS) {
        c->x = B.x; c->y = B.y; 
        return dist(p, B); 
    } 
    return distToLine(p, A, B, c); 
}

int main() {
    int Mx, My;
    while (cin >> Mx) {
        int N, x, y;
        cin >> My >> N;

        point A, B, aux, res, M(Mx, My);
        double dres = numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), d;

        cin >> x >> y;
        A = point(x,y);

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            cin >> x >> y;
            B = point(x,y);

            d = distToLineSegment(M, A, B, &aux);
            if (d < dres) {
                dres = d;
                res = aux;
            }
            A = B;
        }


        printf("%.4f\n%.4f\n",res.x,res.y);
    }
}
```

Now, after changing this lines:

```
int Mx, My;
    while (cin >> Mx) {
        int N, x, y;
        cin >> My >> N;

        point A, B, aux, res, M(Mx, My);
```

To

```
point M;
    while (cin >> M.x) {
        int N, x, y;
        cin >> M.y >> N;

        point A, B, aux, res;
```

My solution got accepted.
Could anyone please help me understand what was the issue with reading the int values and then creating the point? In what possible causes could this code "misbehave" and generate different answers than the other one?
Also, any ideas on why "M" was the only problem? (I kept reading "A" and "B" the same way as before and it didn't affect the answer, only the way I was reading "M" had to be changed).

Any hints to help me understand what is going on would be much appreciated!

---

Edit:
Wrote the constructor wrong when "changing it back to the wrong version", sorry.

Comment: `Mx` is `int` and `M.x` is `double`.

Comment: Could you write the results that you got in both situations ?

Comment: I only glanced for 5 seconds so ignore me if it's irrelevent.. but I notice point constructor takes ints but the members are doubles. Is that right?

Comment: Oh, I was just answring the question, pointing out @johnchen902 comment about integers vs floating-points. But you are correct!  On the other hand, note that the input could contain floating-point numbers. Its not specified what type of numbers are used in the input, and the output talks about floating-point coordinates. So...

Comment: @superarce I can't, because the online judge doesn't give me the test cases, so I don't know in which case I'm failing at... (the answers for the test cases they give are all correct).

Comment: @NeilKirk My mistake, I wrote int on the constructor after "changing back to the wrong version", but the original was double! (edited my question)

Comment: @Manu343726 I didn't think about that,tThat could be the case, but it would be really strange if only some M coordinates were floating point while no segment point at all was a floating point in the whole input... (cause it worked reading that way for A an B). But thanks for the tip!

Comment: @johnchen902 But, shouldn't converting a int to double work fine? And why I have no problems with it for doing the same with points A and B?

Comment: @user2590945 a common problem with UVA judge exampls is that the example contains a little set of input/output samples. The set that the server uses to validate the problem contains thousands of samples. In many cases, a rare type of sample is not specified in the examples..

Answer (score 1):

The difference is wich @jhonchen902 suggest in the comment: The problem specifies output must be floating-point numbers with four digits after the decimal point.

In your first version, you where using integers.

Comment: But I was using the ints just to read the input (which are integer coordinates) and passing them to a constructor that take double as arguments.
Shouldn't converting int to double in this case be ok? If not, why not?

Also, why I get this problem only with M, but it works ok for A and B?

Comment: I have done many UVA judge problems in college, and what I have learned is that the input is not well specified in some cases.

Comment: @user2590945: *The input can contain floating point numbers*. That's where your problem is coming from.